# Older Motobecane conversion

Tags: bottom-bracket, conversion, rear-wheel, europe

I recently acquired an older blue Motobecane Mirage with a great frame and paint.  I have stripped it all down and salvaged everything I can (frame, front wheel, handlebars, front brake) but now I'm left with a quandary.

What type of bottom bracket/crankset/rear wheel will I need?

There is something bizarre about the bike so I've read but I can't find a solid answer.

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear about what you mean by "something bizarre"? And are you wanting to build it up with gears, single-speed, or fixed?

Comment: Take it to a bike shop. Fixing bike problems over the internet is hard enough, and this question is way too sparse on details.

Comment: What exactly are you converting? What do you mean by 'older'?

Comment: @WTHarper I could imagine he means that it's a [French motobecane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motob%C3%A9cane) rather than the new US brand which are produced in Taiwan

Comment: Is the issue the French bottom bracket?

Answer (score 3):

Having converted two 70-something Motobecans, take to your best local shop to figure out what fits your bottom bracket.

As Mikes asked *Is the issue the French bottom bracket?* Or reverse threads?

As a last resort, Velo Orange has a bracket that will work. DO get rid go the cottered cranks!